# Socket.io chat app not showing messages in the DOM

Tags: jquery, socket.io

I'm following the tutorial on socket.io. But I can't print to the dom.

I've tried using vanilla javascript instead of JQuery but it doesn't work either.

Server file

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        io.emit('chat message' + msg);
    });
});

http.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("Magic is happening on http://localhost:" + PORT );
})
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Socket test</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Chat</h2>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>


    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            var socket = io();
            $('form').submit(function() {
                socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
            });
            socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
                window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The result should show a message in the DOM.

But I can only see the message in the terminal.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you create a demo to show how are you connecting to the node js server?

Comment: Sorry, this is a really stupid question, how would I create the demo?

Comment: You can use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla) or any other online code editor that you are familiar with, to recreate the issue and share it with others. More info: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)